# Scope, method return

Tags: java, scope

I been trying to write a program that can display the fibonacci sequence. However any number I input will output 0. I suspect that it has either to do with  scope of the variable or something wrong with my return. could someone look at my code and figure out if it is really those problems? I'm sorta new to java, so even the basic is difficult for me.

```
 public static void main(String args [])
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int number = 0;

    do{
        System.out.print("Which Fibonacci Number would you like? ");
        fib = in.nextInt();
    }while(number < 0 || number > 71);

    System.out.print("Fibonacci #"+number+" is "+fibcalc(fib)+"\n");
}

public static double fibcalc(double number)
{
    double prevNumber1 = 0;
    double prevNumber2 = 1;
    double fib = 0;

    for(int i =0; i < number; i++){
        fib = prevNumber1;
        prevNumber1 = prevNumber2;
        prevNumber2 = fib + prevNumber2;

}
    return fib;
}
```

made some revisions, down to one error.

```
    error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.print("Fibonacci #"+number+" is "+fibcalc(fib)+"\n");
    symbol:   variable fib
```

I got a qucik question.
can one method call upon another method for a variable? the variable is inside of the curly braces. kind of what I have in my code.it seems like most of my errors were similar to this one.

Answer (score 5):

It's nothing to do with scope. Look at this code:

```
while(i < fib){
    fib = prevNumber1;
    ...
}
```

You're using the `fib` variable as both "the number of iterations to execute" and "the current result". Those are two separate concepts, and should be stored in separate variables.

In particular, on the first iteration, `fib` will be set to `0` and `i` will be incremented to 1... so your loop will then terminate, returning 0.

I'd also suggest changing your parameter type to `int` and using `long` or `BigInteger` for the Fibonacci number variables (depending on what range you want to support). There's no part of this problem which needs non-integer values, so you shouldn't be using `double` at all.

Finally, I'd suggest using a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop - you want to perform a given number of iterations, and the idiomatic way of writing that in Java is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // whatever
}
```

Comment: thanks for the pointer, I changed the loop structure changed the orignal     fib to     number.